# How can I give custom pagination for specific page?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-pagination

The code below is working. The requirement is to set custom number of records for 1st page based on `currntWeekAb` where all other pages should have fixed 50 records each.

For example, if the total number of employees is 210 and `currntWeekAb` equals 10, then below code shows `21 pages` when I am on the 1st page and `5 pages` on all other pages. This is because page 1 keeps 10 records and all other pages 50 records each. So the issue here is: **I want to show the same number of pages on all pages, instead of having a different number of pages shown on page 1 compared to all other pages.**

HTML:

```
<table #filteredTable mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" id="table"> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
          <!-- TABLE HEADERs -->       
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="employee ?.length > 0">  
    <tr *ngFor="let of employee | filter: SearchBtn | paginate: config; ; let i = index">
      
          <!-- TABLE RECORDS  -- >   

    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>

<!-- pagination controls -->
<div class="pagination-container">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [id]="config.id" [directionLinks]="true"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class TableComponent {
  // Array of data to be paginated
  employee: any[] = [];
  
  // Pagination settings
  config: PaginationInstance = {
    id: 'custom',
    itemsPerPage: 50,
    currentPage: 1,
    totalItems: this.absences.length
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.retrieveEmp();
  }
  
  // Update the current page when it changes
  onPageChange(pageNumber: number) {
    this.config.currentPage = pageNumber;
    this.config.itemsPerPage = this.config.currentPage === 1 ? this.currntWeekAb() : 50;
  }

 currntWeekAb(){ 
  const filteredAb = this.employee.filter(ab => {
    const startDate = moment(ab['ab_to']).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
    return startDate >= this.filFrom && startDate <= this.filTo || ab.ab_flag == true;
  });
  const totalLength = filteredAb.length;
  c(totalLength)
  return totalLength;
 }

 retrieveEmp():void{
    this.employeeService.getAll()
    .subscribe(
    info => {
      this.employee = info;

      this.config['itemsPerPage'] = this.currntWeekAb() 

    },
    error => {
      c(error);
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you can achieve that by listening to the `pageChange ` event handler and updating the page config dynamically. so basically you can show the more records based on `currntWeekAb ` and then when you switch to next page, update the `itemsPerPage`

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver thats the way I have already done in above code. but its giving the different amount of numbers when I am on 2nd page comapre to 1st.